# c# way of overriding in c++

Tags: c++, interface, overriding

In c# winform we can create an object that overrides certain function of the base class without knowing the implementation of the base. For example we create TouchButton : Button then override the WndProc function only and the implementation of Button is not visible to us.
In c++ I have an interface, for example class IButton which contains all the virtual methods. In my dll implementation it will return the implementation of IButton. Let's say now I want to override certain method without knowing the Button implementation.

```
class TouchButton : public IButton
{
 public:
    IButton& mBase;
    TouchButton(IButton& Base)
        : mBase(Base)
    {};
    void SetSize(int x,int y)
    {
        mBase.SetSize(x,y);
    }
    void Visible(bool v)
    {
        mBase.Visible(v);
    }
    void Click(int x,int y)
    {
        // override
    }
}
```

Ok, now the thing is I want to override only one function but I have to copy and paste these mBase.Function(...) thing again and again, this is definitely not the elegant way of doing it. Is there any better way to archive the same result?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In c# 'we create TouchButton : Button then override the WndProc function only and the implementation of Button is not visible to us' - I think that statement is wrong (Button is fully accessable)

Comment: There's no reason you can't derive from a class whose implementation is hidden (and not just inline in the class).

Comment: Whats wrong with 'class TouchButton : public Button' (without I) ?

Comment: @Dieter Lücking I'm not sure but the winform ui control source code is not visible to us right?

Comment: Like Dieter is saying, you don't need an implementation (= member function bodies) of a class to inherit from it - you just need its definition.

Comment: @Angew I mean even the definition is not visible to me. These implementations could vary between platforms and packed in library. I get certain implementation of the interface from api and want to override one function of this implementation. Like in c# you can have .net 3.5 .net 4.0 their implementation of the Button class might be different but you can still only override one function of it without copying and pasting the base thing everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an IButtonForwarder which stores the reference and does the default forwarding for each member:

```
class IButtonForwarder : public IButton
{
 public:
    IButton& mBase;
    IButtonForwarder(IButton& Base)
        : mBase(Base)
    {};
    virtual void SetSize(int x,int y)
    {
        mBase.SetSize(x,y);
    }
    virtual void Visible(bool v)
    {
        mBase.Visible(v);
    }
    virtual void Click(int x,int y)
    {
        mBase.Visible(v);
    }
};
```

Now your TouchButton just needs to pass the object through and override the appropriate member:

```
class TouchButton : IButtonForwarder
{
 public:
    TouchButton(IButton& Base)
        : IButtonForwarder(Base)
    {};
    virtual void Click(int x,int y)
    {
      // override
    }
};
```

Comment: This approach has one caveat which I think must be mentioned: if the `IButton` implementation held in `mBase` sends itself (its `this`) anywhere, that other party will be totally unaware of `TouchButton` and will bypass any of its overrides.